# How can i add a static vector to a class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a class and i want a vector to live for the the life of the  programe so i am using a static vector.

Please look at my code and advise me if their is better way of using static variable.

```
static std::vector<std::string> Stack;


class Test
{


public:
void AddStack(std::string str)
void PopStack()

};


void Test::AddStack(std::string str)
{

Stack.insert(Stack.end(),str.begin(),str.end());

}


void Test::PopStack()
{

   if(!Stack.empty() )
    {
      Stack.pop_back();

    } 

}
```

Comment: Are you having a particular problem with the code you have so far?  At the very least, you might consider making the `Stack` variable be a `static` member of the `Test` class instead of a global variable.  BTW, are you sure you meant to use `Stack.insert(Stack.end(),str.begin(),str.end());` and not `Stack.push_back(str);` instead?
`

Comment: Code is working fine but i believe the way i have written my code is not the best way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**

Since `Stack` is used solely in the implementation of the member functions of `Test`, make that a `private` and `static` member variable of the class.

```
class Test
{
   public:
      void AddStack(std::string str);
      void PopStack();

   private:
         static std::vector<std::string> Stack;
};
```

and in a .cpp file, add:

```
std::vector<std::string> Test::Stack;
```

**Option 2**

Make `Stack` available to the member functions of `Test` through a function call instead of a variable.

```
class Test
{
   public:
      void AddStack(std::string str);
      void PopStack();

   private:
      static std::vector<std::string>& getStack();
};
```

Implementation:

```
std::vector<std::string>& getStack()
{
   static std::vector<std::string> Stack;
   return Stack;
}

void Test::AddStack(std::string str)
{
   auto& Stack = getStack();
   Stack.insert(Stack.end(),str.begin(),str.end());
}

void Test::PopStack()
{
   auto& Stack = getStack();
   if(!Stack.empty() )
   {
      Stack.pop_back();
   } 
}
```

**Option 3**

Make `Test` a singleton and make `Stack` a non-`static` member of the class.

```
class Test
{
   public:

      static Test& instance();
      void AddStack(std::string str);
      void PopStack();

   private:
      std::vector<std::string> Stack;
};
```

Implementation:

```
Test& Test::instance()
{
   static Test theInstance;
   return theInstance;
}

void Test::AddStack(std::string str)
{
   Stack.insert(Stack.end(),str.begin(),str.end());
}

void Test::PopStack()
{
   if(!Stack.empty() )
   {
      Stack.pop_back();
   } 
}
```

and use it as:

```
Test::instance().AddStack("abcd");
Test::instance().PopStack();
```

Comment: Might also mention that the storage declaration of the `Test::Stack` variable should be in a .cpp file, not in the .h file (if any) that declares the `Test` class, otherwise every unit that includes the .h file will get its own copy of the `Stack` variable, and that will cause conflicts that can be hard to troubleshoot at runtime.

Comment: I would probably go as far as make `Stack` be a **non**-static member of `Test`, and then create a single/static instance of `Test` in the project's main source instead. The end effect would be the same - a single instance of `Stack` for the lifetime of the program

Answer (score 0):

you must be careful with static variables, I suggest to consider this first:

1. Dynamic memory allocation. vectors have bad habit to realloc memory when need more space, and I'm not sure about the impact of dynamic memory allocation with static variables, because static variables are created in heap and you don't want fragmented memory there. The implementation will depends of the compiler, and probably, some fancy option for it.
2. Classes functions related with that variable must be static too, because by definition static variables exist always, and function related must exist always too (easy way to explain). In Other words, static functions only have access to static variables for modifications, and that means a bunch of static functions.

I suggest a nice and easy "export" variable, as I see, does the job without problems/restrictions of static variables.

*blabla.h*

```
export std::vector<std::string> my_no_static_vector;
```

*blabla.cpp*

```
#include "blabla.h"
std::vector<std::string> my_no_static_vector;
```

Comment: A static vector would have its constant-size control block (pointer, size, and allocated_size) stored the same as any static struct.  C++ compilers need to arrange for constructors for static objects to run somehow, and the implementation is platform-specific, but does happen before `main` runs.  When the static vector's constructor runs, it will allocate a buffer and set the pointer.  That allocation will be done the same way as for any other vector, like with `new`.  Similarly, a `vector` local variable doesn't allocate its buffer on the stack, just the control struct.

Comment: Also, re: **2**: you *can* access static class members from non-static member functions.  If you don't access any non-static class members, the function should be static so you can call it without an instance of the class, and because there's no point in generating code to pass a `this` pointer.  Your second sentence is correct, but it's not a summary or an "in other words" of your first sentence.